# *ngFor loop by quantity of items

Tags: arrays, angular, angular8

I have the items array

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Bread",
    "Price": 10,
    "quantity": 4
  },
{
    "Name": "Jam",
    "Price": 2,
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
   "Name": "Butter",
    "Price": 5,
    "quantity": 1
  },
...
]
```

*ngFor="let item of items" loops the items once but I want it to loop each items by the quantity amount, that is the "bread" should be looped 4 times and jam shouldn't show up in the loop.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for your clarified edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better and simpler to create a new array in the javascript:

```
items = [ ... ];
itemQuantities = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.quantity; i++) {
      itemQuantities.push(item);
    }
  });
}
```